"abgekatertes Spiel" synonym mit "abgekartetes Spiel"?
Meiner Recherche nach existieren beide Phrasen. Wörterbüchern nach heiße "abgekartetes Spiel" "im Vorhinein getroffene heimliche Übereinkunft zum Nachteil eines Dritten; Manipulation, Intrige", (1) also, soweit ich verstehe, sowas ähnliches wie "Betrug", wogegen "abgekatertes Spiel" eine Situation sei, in der jemand unter Vorspiegelung falscher Tatsachen Bestellungen aufgebe. (2)
Allerdings habe ich "abgekatertes Spiel" auch im Sinne von "abgekartetes Spiel" verwendet gehört, undzwar in Dragonball Folge 82, ca. bei 12:00. Habt ihr das auch schon in dem Kontext gehört oder ist den Dragonball-Leuten ein Fehler unterlaufen?

Ich habe es noch nie gehört, aber als Wortspiel ist die Wendung "abgekatert" relativ nahe liegend – ein Spiel, aus dem eine männliche Katze entfernt wurde, oder eines, nachdem das Katerfrühstück seine Wirkung erzielt hat.

Der Postillion ist eine Satire-Website, die erfundene Artikel veröffentlicht. Oder wie die Macher selbst es in der FAQ formulieren:


Stimmt das, was im Postillon steht?
Nein, alles, was im Postillon steht, ist Satire und somit dreist zusammengelogen. Alle auftauchenden Charaktere sind fiktional, Ähnlichkeiten mit lebenden Personen sind rein zufällig. Das sollte eigentlich offensichtlich sein, obwohl zahlreiche Kommentare darauf hinweisen, dass vieles hier für bare Münze genommen wird.


Das in der Frage zitierte Video stammt vom Youtube-Kanal Postillion24. Dieser Kanal gehört zum Postillion (und hat übrigens den schönen Untertitel "Postillon24 - Wir berichten, bevor wir recherchieren").
Das heißt: Nein, die Redewendung "ein abgekatertes Spiel" gibt es nicht. Genauso wenig gibt es den Dichter Johann Wolfram von Goethe, auf den sie angeblich zurückgehe. Dieser Dichter hat auch keinen Roman geschrieben, in dem Auermanns Kellner auftauche. Der reale Dichter Johann Wolfgang von Goethe hat in seinem "Faust" eine Szene aus Auerbachs Keller beschrieben, aber das hat mit dieser Frage ja nun überhaupt nichts zu tun ;)
Das Video ist also vollgestopft mit Blödsinn, der ungefähr so ähnlich klingt wie Dinge, die es tatsächlich gibt.

Man beachte, dass der User, der diese Frage gepostet hat, auch einen Postillion-kompatiblen Usernamen hat .....

@user1934428 Ja, aber ist nur so, weil man Google Account so heißt. Mit dem hab ich mich hier angemeldet.

@Henning Kockerbeck Ich kann dich irgendwie nicht taggen. Jedenfalls finde ich diese Satire Nummer von denen so unlustig. Das ist so ein typischer Opferhumor, wenn ihr mich fragt.

Schreib ihnen einen Leserbrief. Die haben eine eigene Rubrik, wo sie sich über Leute lustig machen, die ihren Humor nicht lustig finden, und freuen sich immer über neues Material dafür.
